# Python class OOPs concept

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Snippet 1:

```
class Room(Object):
      pass
```

Snippet 2:

```
class Room():
      pass
```

What is the different between both of the code and why we write object in the above code?

Comment: that is not valid python... it should be `class`, `object`, `pass` (lower case!).

Answer (score 2):

Both are the same in `Python3`.

Read more about it in [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes).

You might want to read [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python) as well.

Search `old style classes vs new style classes in Python`.

Comment: But why we write object what's does it mean

Comment: @VenkatManavarthi It simply means that your defined class is inheriting `Object` class. Although mentioning no name will make no difference at all.